# Puppeteer wait for specific console event

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to implement a function that waits until a certain console event is sent.
E.g. there are several console.endTime calls being done (for performance debugging) and I want to wait until the last one (identified by a specific message text ) is done.
My code kind of works but the problem is that page.on adds new event listeners each time I call my waitForEvent function. I understand  why that happens, but haven't  found a solution that avoids this.

Code looks like this :

```
function waitForEndEvent() {
            return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                registerConsoleEvent(page, res, rej);
            });
        }

function filterMessage() {
        return (msg) => {
            try {
                if (msg.type() == 'timeEnd') {
                    if (msg.text().includes("final time")) {
                        console.log('timeEnd:', msg.text());
                        res();
                    }
                }

            } catch (e) {
                rej(e);
            }
        };
    }
 
function registerConsoleEvent(page, res, rej) {
    page.on('console', filterMessage(res,rej));
}
```

Any hint how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the event listener after receiving the message. You can use the `page.removeListener(...)` method to remove the event listener. So the code would be like this

```js
function waitForEndEvent() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    registerConsoleEvent(page, res, rej);
  });
}

function registerConsoleEvent(page, res, rej) {
  page.on('console', function consoleListener(msg) {
    try {
      if (msg.type() == 'timeEnd') {
        if (msg.text().includes('final time')) {
          console.log('timeEnd:', msg.text());
          page.removeListener('console', consoleListener);
          res();
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rej(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I  had no idea how to remove the listener. I only added a page parameter to the waitForEndEvent function, because it should not be a global object