# Unable to upload files from local system in puppeteer using browser stack. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, puppeteer, browserstack

I am using browser stack local to run my puppeteer scripts. I have browserstack.local set to true in my capabilities list and I have a secure tunnel created between browser stack and my local system. But I am not able to upload a file that is in my project repository. Browser stack is not reading this file. Please help me to solve this issue. How can I upload a file present on my system in my script?

I tried to upload file to browser stack's files and media. But could not figure out where my file is stored.

This is my code to upload the file to a input field

```
let dirname = __dirname; // current directory
let newDirName = dirname.substring(0, dirname.indexOf('src'));   
//getting the path from src folder
//This is function to upload file to a input locator
uploadFile: async (uploadSelector, fileName) => {
    let newPath = path.resolve(newDirName, 'src/util', fileName);
    let uploadButton = await scope.page.$(uploadSelector);
    await uploadButton.uploadFile(newPath);
    await uploadButton.evaluate((upload) =>
        upload.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true 
       }))
    );
}
```

Comment: Please, provide details of your environment, your code, what you attempt to do and what exact error do you get.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context and if possible, include some code, screenshot? That will help us gauge the issue better.

Comment: I have added the code to upload the file to input field on my website. I am trying to upload a 'xlsx' file to a input field using browser stack local. But browser stack is not able to take the xlsx file present in my project folder. There is no error shown by browser stack, but not able to upload my file

Answer (score 0):

Please use the setInputFiles method to upload your file.
You can refer to this documentation for more details:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/playwright/test-file-upload

Thanks.

Comment: Puppeteer does not support waitForEvent function :)

Comment: maybe this link could help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67371657/puppeteer-wait-for-specific-console-event

Answer (score 0):

This one is for selenium, but I guess it can be useful in your case too.

1. Upload your media file on BrowserStack. BrowserStack will make it available in the local disc of the remote machine.
2. Use the path provided in the sample and try to upload your file.

Link for documentation: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/test-file-upload#upload-your-own-media

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked:

Reference: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4405#issuecomment-618581699

Comment: It's better to answer with code in the answer. You can extract the relevant code from the link and use the link as a source. This is because the link might die and then your answer won't be useful to future SO visitors